# How to call Java Executable file with arguments in windows service using c#

Tags: c#

I have java executable file that has to be started automatically on system reboot with out login, we are planing to call that java excutable file with some arguments from windows service.

Can some one suggest me about the how can we achieve it.

Earlier i have used bat file to start executable file, batch file has to start manually(to avoid this we are going for winservice option).

java -jar -Djdbc.driver="<>" -DDB_URL="<>"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Process.Start()

[See Microsoft-docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I have verified possibilities with Process.Start

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did it work? If so please consider upvoting the answer and marking it as accepted.